# Changing Linear layout background color while clicking

Tags: android

I am having a linear layout in my xml and am adding another linear layout(containing two textviews) to that linear layout through java. Touch events works perfect, but i want to highlight the selected linear layout by setting background color. Please advice.

Comment: post the code what you tried

Comment: Implement the Touch or Click events for both the `LinearLayouts` and change its background color according to the selection of layouts.

Comment: Raghunandan has great answer - you should choose it

Answer (score 53):

Define background.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />
<item  android:state_focused="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

normal.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>    
</shape>
```

pressed.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
<solid android:color="#FF1A47"/>      
</shape>
```

Then set background to your layout

```
  android:background="@drawable/background"
```

You can also set the background as below

On Touch of your layout

```
  ll.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            //set color back to default
            ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);  
            break;
            }
            return true;        
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 14):

Regardless of the method you chose (XML/code) - make sure you make your `LinearLayout` clickable:

XML:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Code:

```
myLinearLayout.setClickable(true);
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution, it's very simple:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_pressed_tab"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/service_request"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

            <requestFocus />
        </LinearLayout>
```

bg_tab_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" />

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" />

</selector>
```

Comment: this solutions works perfectly and toggles the background when you have  2 or more of such viewgroups and you want to show only one of them highlighted.  

But it will fail in some cases like if there is other view's like edit text in the layout that would take the focus away.

Answer (score 2):

put selector.xml file in drawable folder (res/drawable)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_focused" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_raw_img"/>

</selector>
```

and set background of your linear layout in xml file

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Comment: incorrect, you can't name the file selector.xml then call @drawable/background and expect it to work

Answer (score 2):

The following method will get you want you want. Even the ripple animation in Lollipop. Just pass a context the the view (can be a linear layout):

```
public static void setClickableAnimation(final Context context, final View view) {
    final int[] attrs = new int[]{R.attr.selectableItemBackground};
    final TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
    final int backgroundResource = typedArray.getResourceId(0, 0);
    view.setBackgroundResource(backgroundResource);
    typedArray.recycle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `View` function `setBackgroundColor()`

See the Android docs:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor%28int%29

```
public void setBackgroundColor (int color)       Added in API level 1
    Sets the background color for this view.
Parameters
    color   the color of the background
```